# How to view Disabled wordpress page content

Tags: wordpress

I used to have a wordpress site but recently switched to a custom based HTML site and the .htaccess file has been edited to not show any wordpress content.

Now I am supposed to look at a wp page content specifically.
so i go to wp_posts table and searched for post_type = page. I got my post_title and post_content. But in my post_content i see a link for the content www.xxx.com/franchising/costs.

I was just wondering where is this content stored or where does this link content stored in.

If its not possible to retreive the content, is my only option to restore my wordpress in .htaccess and look for my content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be in the `post_name` field in `wp_posts`.

Comment: The post_name is showing only the name "COSTS" and post_content has a <a href="www.xxxxx.com/franchsing/costs">Costs</a> tag.  I was just trying to find out the costs content associated with this post. Thank you.